# What replaces wpColorPicker in Gutenberg?

Tags: block-editor

With `wpColorPicker` available in `color-picker.min.js`, I was able to easily create color fields which simply display the color:

[image: Show color]

When you click the field, a color picker appears:

[image: Change color]

Now I want to do the same with Gutenberg components. However, I cannot find the exact replacement for `wpColorPicker`:

- `ColorPicker` from `@wordpress/components` is the picker itself, where the user is invited to choose a color. It doesn't seem to implement the "show" state. It's not a full-fledged form control.
- `ColorIndicator` from `@wordpress/components` only shows a color.
- `ColorPalette` from `@wordpress/components` does too much. Using the palette with an empty color set does not work either, it was not designed for this use case.
- `PanelColorSettings` and `withColors` from `@wordpress/block-editor` are even higher level.
- Using the Storybook's stories of the Gutenberg project, I can see that the latest `ColorPalette` does what I'm looking for, but it doesn't behave that way in WordPress 5.8.1.

[image: Latest ColorPalette]

There is an obvious way to get the job done: write a `ColorControl` component based on `ColorIndicator`, `ColorPicker` and `Dropdown`, or simply steal from the latest `ColorPalette`.

But I'm wondering if a ready-to-use component is already available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own `ColorControl`. I'm not satisfied with this solution and I don't advice you to follow this route blindly. However, if you want to get the job done and don't want to spend two hours on something that might not exist as I did, here you go.

Install two extra packages:

```
npm install styled-components colord
```

The code:

```
import React from 'react'

const {
  BaseControl,
  Dropdown,
  ColorPicker,
  Button
} = wp.components;

import styled from'styled-components';
import { colord } from 'colord';

const DropWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-top: 8px;
`;

const ColorButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${props => props.value};
  color: ${props => colord(props.value).isLight() ? '#1e1e1e' : '#fff'};
  min-width: 150px;
`;

const ColorControl = (props) => (
  <BaseControl
    label={props.label}
  >
    <DropWrapper>
      <Dropdown
        renderContent={() => (
          <ColorPicker
            color={props.value}
            onChangeComplete={color => props.onChange(color.hex)}
          />
        )}
        renderToggle={ ( { isOpen, onToggle } ) => (
          <ColorButton
            aria-expanded={ isOpen }
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={ onToggle }
            aria-label={ `${props.label} color picker` }
            value={ props.value }
          >
            { props.value }
          </ColorButton>
        ) }
      />
    </DropWrapper>
  </BaseControl>
);

export default ColorControl;
```

The field:

[image: My color picker]

When you click it:

[image: My color picked - clicked]